# ESP8266 + DHT11 AWS IOT Thing not updating thing shadow - was working before

Tags: esp8266, iot

I was able to get this working - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hpro1olRK0 - send an SMS and email of temperature and humidity data from AWS IOT using esp8266 + dht11 but all of a sudden it stopped updating the shadow.

Here is the code

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <DHT11.h>
#include <AmazonIOTClient.h>
#include <ESP8266AWSImplementations.h>

Esp8266HttpClient httpClient;
Esp8266DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider;

AmazonIOTClient iotClient;
ActionError actionError;

const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";

// Pin 2 will be used to read sensor data
int pin = 2;

// Initializing the sensor
DHT11 dht11(pin);

//Function to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
double Fahrenheit(double celsius) {
  return ((celsius * 9 / 5) + 32);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println();

  // Connecting to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  iotClient.setAWSRegion("us-west-2");
  iotClient.setAWSEndpoint("amazonaws.com");
  iotClient.setAWSDomain("al1x5kb4rzh0x.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com");
  iotClient.setAWSPath("$aws/things/esp8266/shadow/update/accepted");
  iotClient.setAWSKeyID("AKIAJJQ6ASLIDIPBE4PQ");
  iotClient.setAWSSecretKey("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");
  iotClient.setHttpClient(&httpClient);
  iotClient.setDateTimeProvider(&dateTimeProvider);
}

void loop() {
  int err;
  float temp, humi;

//Reading the sensor data
  if ((err = dht11.read(humi, temp)) == 0) {
    Serial.print(" temperature:");
    Serial.print(temp);
    Serial.print(" humidity:");
    Serial.print(humi);
    Serial.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(" Error No :");
    Serial.print(err);
    Serial.println();

  }
// Converting the float data to char arrays
  char sTemp[10], sHumi[10];
  dtostrf(humi, 6, 2, sHumi);
  dtostrf(temp, 6, 2, sTemp);

// Creating the thing shadow to be sent to aws iot
  char shadow[100];
  strcpy(shadow, "{\"state\":{\"reported\": {\"Humidity\":");
  strcat(shadow, sHumi);
  strcat(shadow, ", \"Temperature\":");
  strcat(shadow, sTemp);
  strcat(shadow, "}}}");
  Serial.print(shadow);

  char* result = iotClient.update_shadow(shadow, actionError);
  Serial.print(result);

  delay(60000);
}
```

Output as expected

```cpp
Connecting to 
NETGEAR53
.........
WiFi connected
 temperature:31.00 humidity:32.00
{"state":{"reported": {"Humidity": 32.00, "Temperature": 31.00}}}al1x5kb4rzh0x.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
443
POST $aws/things/esp8266/shadow/update/accepted HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: close
Content-Length: 65
Host: al1x5kb4rzh0x.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256: 923ed1ae613a9e14b45e4d080b092daf5cf61118041dc5225956299d5b0f8d49
x-amz-date: 20180323T034259Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJJQ6ASLIDIPBE4PQ/20180323/us-west-2/iotdata/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=a10f0969043e609743412478567c10290b8c000185f2824e4a9cf07bb96cf279

{"state":{"reported": {"Humidity": 32.00, "Temperature": 31.00}}}
```

Comment: #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <DHT11.h>
#include <AmazonIOTClient.h>
#include <ESP8266AWSImplementations.h>

Esp8266HttpClient httpClient;
Esp8266DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider;

AmazonIOTClient iotClient;
ActionError actionError;

Comment: A small correction on the output, sometimes its perfect but some other times  i get timeout receiving time server data

{"state":{"reported": {"Humidity": 41.00, "Temperature": 31.00}}}al1x5kb4rzh0x.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
443

POST /things/ESP/shadow HTTP/1.1

------------------------
{"state":{"reported": {"Humidity": 41.00, "Temperature": 31.00}}}timeout receiving timeserver data

Comment: I am also facing the same problem and still, I didn't get any answer...current I am also working on that

Comment: Anyone get this solved? I have the same issue

Comment: I am planning to try cleaning the AWSiot libraries, that worked last time but again only one device works for me as of now. Probably I might try a different set of code. Please share your code guys -- I will try to help. Also I am trying different AWS keys.

Comment: Pls post the aws iot libraries you are using. Ot sure what changed but nothing works and thing shadow not getting updated

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem: trying to update a thing's shadow on AWS IoT with no success. After some research, I found out that I was using an **outdated library**. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378582/connecting-esp8266-to-aws-iot#40519144) they advise to use *heskew*'s `aws-sdk-arduino`, on `iot-get-shadow-and-cleanup` branch:

https://github.com/heskew/aws-sdk-arduino/tree/iot-get-shadow-and-cleanup.

Additionally, I think you have a little error on your code. As far as I know, `AWSPath`, it should look like:

```
iotClient.setAWSPath("/things/esp8266/shadow");
```

At least that works for me, and they use it this way on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJuXv5usXcY).

That's all I can tell... I am learning at this moment as well.
Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, really appreciate it. My thing name is actually ESP so i have it set as ---iotClient.setAWSPath("/things/ESP/shadow");--- or should it only be esp8266? 

i deleted old libraries and used the one above but still my thing shadow is not updating. Please help. The other example video you referred - that also is not working

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/51059/esp8266-dht11-aws-iot-thing-not-updating-thing-shadow-was-working-before

Answer (score 1):

Just Change the Aws topic :
it should be  $aws/things/esp8266/shadow/update

and you have to add the certificate path also